# Roll, pitch, yaw calculation

Tags: 3d, robotics

How can I calculate the roll, pitch and yaw angles associated with a homogeneous transformation matrix?

I am using the following formulas at the moment, but I am not sure whether they are correct or not.

```
pitch = atan2( -r20, sqrt(r21*r21+r22*r22) );
yaw   = atan2(  r10, r00 );
roll  = atan2(  r21, r22 );
```

r10 means second row and first column.

Comment: yes you are right but my point is how can I calculate angle beyond this limit..

Comment: @Sh3ljohn no I am not satisfied because I know these things already. I found another way to find out roll pitch yaw, kindly see this link http://code.google.com/p/matlab-toolboxes-robotics-vision/source/browse/matlab/robot/tags/R9.4/tr2rpy.m?r=822 ..Do you know what should be input for this matlab function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your equations are correct *only if* the order of rotations is: roll, then pitch, then yaw. For the record, the correspondence with Euler angles (with respect to the frame of reference implicitly given with the transformation matrix) is as follows:

- *Roll* is the rotation about the **x axis** (between -180 and 180 deg);
- *Pitch* is the rotations about the **y axis** (between -90 and 90 deg);
- *Yaw* is the rotation about the **z axis** (between -180 and 180).

Given these, the order *roll, pitch, yaw* mentioned in the first sentence corresponds to the rotation matrix obtain by the matrix product `Rz Ry Rx` (in this order). Note that your formula give the values of these angles **in radians** (multiply by 180 and divide by pi to obtain values in degrees). All rotations are counter-clockwise with respect to the axis.

[image]
*Figure taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Yaw_Axis_Corrected.svg)*

---

Following your comment about [this](https://code.google.com/p/matlab-toolboxes-robotics-vision/source/browse/matlab/robot/tags/R9.4/tr2rpy.m?r=822) link, I think [this paper](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/transformationprojection/Aij-to-Eulerangles.pdf) might help to understand the program you are referring to. The input to the Matlab function is supposed to be your transformation matrix, followed by 'deg' if you want the angles to be returned in degrees, and an obsolete option 'zyx' if the order of the rotations is around z, then around y, then around x.

Comment: okay now we have two formulas one that I am using right now and the one shown in matlab program but they are totally different with each other, so my confusion is which formula should I use? I have transformation matrix and I want to calculate roll pitch yaw with respect to fixed reference frame(roll pitch yaw not euler angles).

Answer (score 2):

[This might be better suited as a comment but it is to long for that ;) ]

When I compare your formula with the one on the german Wikipedia page about roll, pitch an yaw ([see here](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roll-Nick-Gier-Winkel#Berechnung_aus_Rotationsmatrix)) there is a difference in the calculation of the pitch. According to Wikipedia your formula should look like this:

```
pitch = atan2(-r20,(sqrt(pow(r21,2)+pow(r00,2))); // replaced r22 by r00
```

Note that on the wikipedia page they use a different indexing for the matrix elements (thex start with 1 and not with 0 for the first row/column). Furthermore they call pitch beta, yaw alpha and roll gamma. Also, they divide the coefficents for `atan2` in the yaw and roll calculation by the `cos(pitch)`, but that should cancel out.

Otherwise your formula looks fine to me.

Comment: I think it's a mistake on the German Wikipedia then, r22 looks fine.

Comment: formula is correct I think but if you closely look at formula for pitch you will find that denominator always remain positive, as per my knowledge atan2 compute quadrant according to sign of numerator and denominator. this is exactly my problem when I am increasing pitch greater than 90degree it will start to decrease..

Answer (score 0):

"Roll is the rotation about the x axis (between -180 and 180 deg);
Pitch is the rotations about the y axis (between -90 and 90 deg);
Yaw is the rotation about the z axis (between -180 and 180)."

There is a mistake in this quoted answer posted above. While the figure is accurate, the "roll" and the "pitch" have been interchanged in the quoted answer. It should read:

"Roll is the rotation about the y axis ...;
Pitch is the rotations about the x axis ...;
Yaw is the rotation about the z axis ..."

I hope this was helpful to you.

Comment: [NED coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_tangent_plane_coordinates#Local_north.2C_east.2C_down_.28NED.29_coordinates) has roll about x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the equations from the next picture. The complimentary/Kalman filter is there in order to get less noise.
[image: Calculate Eulers angles from sensors]