# Xamarin.Forms - get pitch, roll, yaw from gyroscope sensor

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, gyroscope

I need sufficient way to calculate Yaw, Pitch, Roll from gyroscope sensor

I am using Xamarin.Essentials to read X, Y, Z values, and these works just fine

but when I tried to calculate Yaw, Pitch, Roll it give me wrong values using this method

```cs
void Gyroscope_ReadingChanged(object sender, GyroscopeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var data = e.Reading;
    // Process Angular Velocity X, Y, and Z reported in rad/s
    Console.WriteLine($"Reading_Gyroscope_1: X: {data.AngularVelocity.X}, Y: {data.AngularVelocity.Y}, Z: {data.AngularVelocity.Z}");

    GyroX = data.AngularVelocity.X ;
    GyroY = data.AngularVelocity.Y ;
    GyroZ = data.AngularVelocity.Z ;
    var roll =  Math.Atan(GyroY / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(GyroX, 2.0) + Math.Pow(GyroZ, 2.0)));
    var pitch = Math.Atan(GyroX / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(GyroY, 2.0) + Math.Pow(GyroZ, 2.0)));
    var yaw = Math.Atan(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(GyroX, 2.0) + Math.Pow(GyroZ, 2.0)) / GyroZ);

    Console.WriteLine($"Reading_Gyroscope_2: X: {GyroX}, Y: {GyroY}, Z: {GyroZ} roll: {roll} pitch: {pitch} yaw:{yaw}");
}
```

any hind what is the best way to calculate these variables

**UPDATE** the reason why I think its wrong I am using these variables to update my video position using a gyroscope

here is the method used

```cs
/// <param name="yaw">view point yaw in degrees  ]-180;180]</param>
/// <param name="pitch">view point pitch in degrees  ]-90;90]</param>
/// <param name="roll">view point roll in degrees ]-180;180]</param>
/// <param name="fov">field of view in degrees ]0;180[ (default 80.)</param>
/// <param name="absolute">if true replace the old viewpoint with the new one. If false, increase/decrease it.</param>
/// <returns>true if successful, false otherwise</returns>
public bool UpdateViewpoint (float yaw, float pitch, float roll, float fov, bool absolute = true);
```

Comment: This seems to be a math question, not a xamarin question. Try math.stackexchange.com

Comment: yea it's a math equation but its related to sensors so thats why I post it here

Comment: Maybe google ‘calculate yaw pitch roll from angular velocity’?

Comment: Thanks I will try this one

Comment: Also, I recommend writing some test cases. Show Angular Velocity, the expected yaw pitch roll outputs, the actual yaw pitch roll outputs. Maybe there’s some minor mistake that totally changes the result. Someone might spot it, given test data. If you find an online formula, but still have wrong answer, add link to that source, to question.

Comment: I just realized you use atan. I’m not familiar with yaw pitch roll formulas, but most computed geometry formulas prefer atan2, to get correct quadrant. Test data would make this type of wrong answer easier to spot.

Comment: I think you need to figure out the math **first**, then write the code.  Angular Velocity is reported in rad/s, converting that to a static pitch/roll/yaw value is a more complex process than what you have.  There are numerous discussions about this on various SE sites, including SO

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve atan2 takes two params, I don't know what the second params, Jason I am trying to figure out how converting rad/s patch values

Comment: If you find some discussion that says how to convert angular velocity to the equivalent "homogenous transformation matrix", then from that matrix you can apply [formulas in this question; but read the answer for more explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23010193/199364).

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, but you need to solve the **math** part before you can write any code.  Perhaps try https://math.stackexchange.com/